# Regex starts with Capital letter and having length < 70

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to match a string starting with capital letter and have length < 70.

I tried this regex `([A-Z][a-zA-Z\s\/\-]*\:?\'?)` to check if the string starts with capital letter. It is working fine. But to check length, I changed to `(([A-Z][a-zA-Z\s\/\-]*\:?\'?){4,70})` and it is not working.

Though, I can check the length using `length()` method of string in `if` statement. Doing so would make `if` statement lengthy. I want to combine length checking in regex itself. I think it can be done in regex, but I am not sure how.

**Update(Forgot to mention):** String can have either of two symbol- **:**,**'** and only one of two will be there for either zero or one time in the string.

**E.g :** Acceptable String : `Looking forwards to an opportunity`, `WORK EXPERIENCE:` , `WORK EXPERIENCE-` , `India's Prime Minister`

UnAcceptable String : `Work Experience::` , `Manager's Educational Qualification-` , `work experience:` , `Education - 2014 - 2017` , `Education (Graduation)`

Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll certainly need anchors and lookarounds

```
(?=^[^-':\n]*[-':]{0,1}[^-':\n]*$)^[A-Z][-':\w ]{4,70}$
```

Thus, a string between 5-71 characters will be matched, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wMx6iL/4/). Additionally, it checks for the presence of zero or one of your Special characters (with the help of lookarounds, that is).

Comment: I think the `$` is obsolete in this case as `.{4,70}` matches *anything* for a maximum of 70 times. So if *anything* is inputted after that, it should not be matched anyway.

Comment: It is allowing special symbol other than mentioned in question, which should not happen.

Comment: @OmPrakash: Please provide some strings that are valid and some you want to disallow.

Comment: @Jan Ah, I didn't know about the special handling of line separators. Nice catch!

Comment: Updated the answer to include lookarounds.

Answer (score 3):

I would add `^` and `$` to your regex:

```
^[A-Z].{,69}$
```

should work.  This means:

- `^` beginning of the string
- `[A-Z]` any capital character (in English anyway)
- `.{0,69}` up to 69 other characters
- `$` end of the string

for a total length of up to 70 characters...

Answer (score 1):

why would the `if` statement be lengthy?

```
    String str = "Scary";

    if (str.length() < 70 && str.charAt(0) >= 'A') {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a lookaround assertion at the start of the regex that asserts that it may contain between 4 and 70 characters :

```
(?=.{4,70}$)
```

You would write so :

```
String regex = "(?=.{4,70}$)[A-Z][a-zA-Z\\s\\/\\-]*\\:?\\'?";
```

Answer (score -1):

Working REGEX =

```
/\A^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\z/
```

Comment: This lacks the length constraint.